# where to destroy knex connection

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm using [knex](https://knexjs.org/) with [pg](https://www.postgresql.org/).

I have a project similar as following.

dbClient.js

```
const dbClient = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'staging',
    port: '5431'
  }
})

module.exports = dbClient
```

libs.js

```
const knex = require('./dbClient.js')

async function doThis(email) {
  const last = await knex('users').where({email}).first('last_name').then(res => res.last_name)
  // knex.destroy()
  return last
}

async function doThat(email) {
  const first = await knex('users').where({email}).first('first_name').then(res => res.first_name)
  // knex.destroy()
  return first
}

module.exports = {
  doThat,
  doThis
}
```

test01.js

```
const {doThis, doThat} = require('./libs.js');

(async () => {
  try {
    const res1 = await doThis('user53@gmail.com')
    console.log(res1)
    const res2 = await doThat('user53@gmail.com')
    console.log(res2)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})()
```

When `knex.destroy()` was removed from `libs.js` as shown above. `node test01` could output `res1` and `res2`. But the issue is the connection hangs indefinitely and CMD never return.

But if I uncomment `knex.destroy()` from `libs.js`, then `doThis` will execute, CMD will hangs at `doThat` as there's no connection anymore which has been closed in `doThis`.

My question is :

What is the best location for `knex.destroy()`? Or there's other ways to do it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Don't know if I understand right. If `knex` used in server app, it's OK not to call `knex.destroy()`. but if `knex` was used in client app, we need to call `knex.destroy()` somewhere ?

Comment: For others who are confused by the conversation - the OP specifically want their Mocha test suite to exit cleanly - which requires destroying open connections. Calling knex.destroy(done) does this, where done is the callback passed to Mocha's after() hook

Comment: I personally never destroy the connection manually. Instead I call `process.exit()` when I'm done

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Knex [destroy()](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling) seems to be a one time operation. After destroying a connection, one might require a brand new connection pool for the next operation.

The db client module you export [is cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) into node module cache and a new connection pool is not created every time you require it.

This is intended usage, the pool is supposed to be destroyed when app exits or all the tests are done. If you have reasons to create/destroy connections for every operation ( like in serverless environment) you should not reuse the destroyed client, rather create a new instance every time.

Otherwise, it defeats the purpose of connection pooling.

---

**Update** about lambda/server-less environments:

Technically a function and its resources are to be released after the lambda function has run, this includes any connections it might have opened. This is necessary for truly stateless functions. Therefore it is advisable to close connection when function is done. However, a lot of functions opening/closing a lot of connections may eventually make the DB server run out of connections (see [this discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216000&start=0&tstart=0) for example). One solution might be to use an intermediate pool like [PgBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/) or [PgPool](https://www.pgpool.ne) that negotiates connections between DB server and Lambda functions.

<s>The other way is for the platform provider (AWS) to add special pooling capabilities to lambda environment and let them share long-lived resources.</s>

**Update 2**
AWS has launched a proxy for RDS that caters to the problem of massive connection loads towards RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/

Comment: so which means, if `test01.js` is my main app, then better put `knex.destroy()` at the end of `test01.js` ?

Comment: @mCY Unless there is a special requirement to close all connections, you **do not need** to use destroy() in your app or tests.

Comment: but in my codes above, if I don't call `knex.destroy()` somewhere, then `node test01.js` will hangs there and will never return. The way I use knex is with Mocha. So I was thinking if need to have a teardown script to close the connection. If not, again it will hang ?

Comment: I had to call .destroy() to end the process without having to call process.exit(0);

Comment: @S.D. you mean to say that for server-less environment like Rest API, the application need to make connections every time and destroy.

Comment: @waseemasgar Yes it is the recommended approach. See updated answer.

Comment: @S.D. correct me if i am wrong. As per your answer, use of knex is not good in case of rest api (due to pool). or is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @waseemasgar No. The current design of lambda is against pooling, which has been a common pattern in traditional server design. It doesn't have anything to do with REST or KnexJS being incompatible.

Comment: @S.D. With knex, what should the pool setting look like when using PgBouncer? I have multiple Node apps all connecting to the same DB and each having its own pool is an efficiency nightmare. If I se PgBouncer and connect to it via Knex, what do I pass for min and max values for the pool size to make this work?

Comment: @ankush981 For stateless lambda invocation, the ideal will be to have no pooling on knex side (since we have PgBouncer doing it to the DB). Which means a `min:0` setting on knex. The `max` setting depends on how many parallel queries are executed in single lambda invocation, but I'll advise to keep it to `max:1` for most simple cases.

Answer (score 10):

Destroying the connection after every query is like packing your guitar up every time you play a note. Just pull it out at the beginning of the performance, play all the songs and put it away at the end.

Likewise, destroy the connection when you're done with it for the rest of the application, not after each query like this. In a web server, this is probably never since you're going to kill it with a signal at some indeterminate point and an active connection is likely a necessity for the app until then.

For tests, you'll probably want to make use of the `destroy` function to avoid hanging. Similarly, in an (contrived?) application like you've shown, if you are experiencing a hang and the app gets stuck, destroy the connection one time when you're done with it.

Here's an illustrative example for Mocha, which was mentioned in a comment and seems like a pretty reasonable assumption that it (or something similar) is being used by folks who wind up in this thread. The pattern of setting up before all tests, tearing down after all tests, and doing per-test case setup and teardown is generic.

Relevant to your question, `after(() => knex.destroy());` is the teardown call at the end of all tests. Without this, Mocha hangs. Note that we also shut down the http server per test so there are multiple candidates for hanging the test suite to look out for.

#### `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");

const createServer = (knex, port=3000) => {
  const app = express();
  
  app.get("/users/:username", (request, response) => {
    knex
      .where("username", request.params.username)
      .select()
      .first()
      .table("users")
      .then(user => user ? response.json({data: user})
                         : response.sendStatus(404))
      .catch(err => response.sendStatus(500))
  });
  
  const server = app.listen(port, () =>
    console.log(`[server] listening on port ${port}`)
  );
  return {
    app,
    close: cb => server.close(() => {
      console.log("[server] closed");
      cb && cb();
    })
  };
};
module.exports = {createServer};
```

#### `server.test.js`:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const {createServer} = require("./server");
const {expect} = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0;

describe("server", function () {
  this.timeout(3000);
  let knex;
  let server;
  let app;
  
  before(() => {
    knex = require("knex")({
      client: "pg",
      connection: "postgresql://postgres@localhost",
    });
  });
  beforeEach(done => {
    server = createServer(knex);
    app = server.app;
    knex
      .schema
      .dropTableIfExists("users")
      .then(() => 
        knex.schema.createTable("users", table => {
          table.increments();
          table.string("username");
        })
      )
      .then(() => knex("users").insert({
        username: "foo"
      }))
      .then(() => done())
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });
  afterEach(done => server.close(done));
  after(() => knex.destroy());
  
  it("should get user 'foo'", done => {
    chai
      .request(app)
      .get("/users/foo")
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(response).to.be.json;
        expect(response.body).to.be.instanceOf(Object);
        expect(response.body.data).to.be.instanceOf(Object);
        expect(response.body.data.username).to.eq("foo");
        done();
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  });
});
```

#### Packages:

```
"knex": "0.21.6",
"express": "4.17.1",
"mocha": "8.0.1",
"pg": "8.3.0",
```

Node 12.19.0.

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't usually need to explicitly call `knex.destroy()` – this is implied by the documentation itself saying (emphasis mine):

> *If you ever need to* explicitly teardown the connection pool, you may use `knex.destroy([callback])`.

Comment: If I don't call `knex.destroy()` my script will hang. Then what does it mean `we don't need to explicitly call knex.destroy()` ?

Comment: Ah, you only mentioned elsewhere that this is for Mocha. For regular server uses you don't need to tear down the connection pool – for Mocha, you might want to look into a global teardown hook, see https://futurestud.io/tutorials/mocha-global-setup-and-teardown-before-after